# Is there a way to make a single type Paragraphs field not required?

Tags: 9, paragraphs

My Content Type has a Paragraphs field that is Not required. The Paragraph type has a required field for when it is added, but until it is added, this shouldn't trigger "required" for my field. Since my field only has 1 paragraph type option, it is ALWAYS added! I can Remove the paragraph from the field, and required doesn't get triggered. But every time the form loads to add a new node, it always adds a paragraph.

e.g.

- Paragraph type: Image with caption has an image as a required field.
- Content type has a field: Photo of that paragraph type that is not required.
- Add content shows paragraph automatically added and required.

Is this a bug, or a setting I'm missing?

Comment: I’m the Form display settings for your content type, configure your paragraph field to **not** add a default paragraph.

Comment: Thanks! It's called **Default paragraph type** and I just had to set it to `- None -`